# Text splitting by marker using Spacy

Tags: python, text, spacy

I can't solve a problem that seems simple: I need to join the sentences in the text into one line and to separate these lines depending on the marker.

```py
import spacy
import re
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
txt_marked = """
"Hi! This is the first sentence!
This is the second sentence on a new line!
This is the third sentence on the new line!
This is a MARKER
This is the fourth sentence on a new line!
This is the fifth sentence on the new line!
It's a MARKER!
This is the sixth sentence on the new line!
This is the eighth sentence on the new line!»
"""
doc = nlp(txt_marked)
a=list(doc.sents)
b=""
for sentens in a:
    if "MARKER" not in str(sentens):
       b+=str(sentens)  
    elif "MARKER" in str(sentens):
       b+'\n'
print(b)
```

I want it like so:

```py
"Hi! This is the first sentence! This is the second sentence on the new line! This is the third sentence on the new line!

This is the fourth sentence on the new line! This is the fifth sentence on the new line!

This is the sixth sentence on the new line! This is the eighth sentence on the new line!"
```

But it doesn't work. It gives:

```py
"Hi!This is the first sentence!
 This is the second sentence on a new line!
 This is the third sentence on the new line!
 This is the fourth sentence on a new line!
 This is the fifth sentence on the new line!
 This is the sixth sentence on the new line!
 This is the eighth sentence on the new line!»
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your sentences:

```py
[' '.join((a.strip() for a in y) 
   for x, y in groupby(
    doc.sents, lambda x: 'MARKER' not in x) if x]

[' "Hi! This is the first sentence! This is the second sentence on a new line! This is the third sentence on the new line!', 'This is the fourth sentence on a new line! This is the fifth sentence on the new line!', 'This is the sixth sentence on the new line! This is the eighth sentence on the new line!»']
```

Or, in your for loop

```py
for x, y in groupby(doc.sents, lambda x: 'MARKER' not in x):
    if not x:
        continue
    print(' '.join(a.strip() for a in y))

"Hi! This is the first sentence! This is the second sentence on a new line! This is the third sentence on the new line!
This is the fourth sentence on a new line! This is the fifth sentence on the new line!
This is the sixth sentence on the new line! This is the eighth sentence on the new line!»
```

Answer (score 0):

(old posted I know)
I think the problem is that you are just printing the sentens.

But had a similar problem. If you are using token and placing them a graph there is the same problem. The line brakes are combined as one token as ("/n/n/n").

You could use `repr(token.text)`

It gives you "/n/n/n"
with this you can calculate the amount of /n and get the space you need.

```
text = repr(token.text)

x = text.count('/n') (doesn't work somehow) 
x = text = (len(label)-2)/2 (works, -2 because of the '')
```